# Dynamic DynamoDB doesn't seem to calculate Scale up Amount Correctly

Tags: dynamic, amazon-dynamodb

I started working with Dynamic DynamoDB recently in AWS to handle spikes in throughput in some of our tables.   I thought I understood the documentation, but Dynamic DynamoDB doesn't seem to work like I expected.

Dynamic DynamoDB recognizes that it should scale up and sends the notification.  Then when it calculates the amount to scale up, it calculates what the current Read pr visioning units are.

It is currently set to 30 units and the log states that it will scale up to 30.0.
This doesn't look correct to me.

Can anyone see what my issue is.   Here is what I see in the log:

```
dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - MY_TABLE - Currently provisioned read units: 30
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - Consumed read units: 67%
dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - MY_TABLE - Currently provisioned write units: 5
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - Consumed write units: 0%
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - Will send high provisioning alert
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - Sent SNS notification to arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789:DynamicDB_DEV
dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - MY_TABLE - Currently provisioned read units: 30
dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - MY_TABLE - Currently provisioned read units: 30
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - Consumed read units: 67%
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - Read throttle count: 0
dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - MY_TABLE - Read provisioning will be increased to 30.0 units
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - Consecutive read checks 0/1
dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - MY_TABLE - Currently provisioned write units: 5
dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - MY_TABLE - Currently provisioned write units: 5
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - Consumed write units: 0%
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - Write throttle count: 0
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - Scaling down writes is not done when usage is at 0% 
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - Consecutive write checks 0/1
dynamic-dynamodb - INFO - MY_TABLE - No need to change provisioning
dynamic-dynamodb - DEBUG - Sleeping 300 seconds until next check
```

*Here is the relevant section of the config file:*

```
[table: ^MY_TABLE$]
#
# Read provisioning configuration
#

# Thresholds for trigging throughput alarm to send notification (%)
reads-upper-alarm-threshold: 65
#reads-lower-alarm-threshold: 30

# Enable or disable reads autoscaling  SHOULDN't need this, but I'll try anything
enable-reads-autoscaling = true

# Enable reads up or down scaling
# Note: Those controls will not have any effect if enable-reads-autoscaling is false
enable-reads-up-scaling = true
enable-reads-down-scaling = true

# Thresholds for scaling up or down the provisioning (%)
# Scales reads up when 90% capacity, scales down reads when 30% capacity
reads-upper-threshold: 65
reads-lower-threshold: 30

# How many percent should Dynamic DynamoDB increase/decrease provisioning with (%)
increase-reads-with: 50
decrease-reads-with: 50

# Units to increase or decrease reads with, must be either percent or units
increase-reads-unit: percent
decrease-reads-unit: percent

# Maximum and minimum read provisioning
# Dynamic DynamoDB will not provision any more or less reads than this
min-provisioned-reads: 30
max-provisioned-reads: 75
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  It is not really clear what your problem statement is here.

Comment: The read throughput is set to 30.  When the threshold is crossed of 65% capacity ( based on how I have the configuration file set), I expect the reads to scale up by 50%.  In the logs you can see that the daemon determined that it needs to scale up, although the message indicates "Read provisioning will be increased to 30.0 units".   30 units is what it is currently configured at, I would expect it to scale up to 45.

Comment: This issue was identified as a bug and was fixed in version 1.20.3.
Reference: https://github.com/sebdah/dynamic-dynamodb/issues/235

Comment: Could you mark the Github issue as the answer?